# Display prompt MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-3.0

```
   [Display(Prompt = "Scheme", Name = "Scheme")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Scheme Name Required")]
        public string name { get; set; }
```

The dsiplay prompt doesnt works in Ie 8 ,is ther any alternative method to put watermark on textbox???

Comment: What does it actually do? You need to provide more information.

Comment: well i want to put watermark on textbox , but the display prompt method not working in ie9 only working in chrome

Comment: what is your html/razor markup?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a jQuery plug in like this one: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/updnWatermark